# UFT Exception while putting breakpoint

Tags: exception, breakpoints, qtp

I am getting the below exception whenever I am putting a break-point in the script and running it. UFT throws the below exception and asks me to quit or restart the application(UFT). This is specific to a project only and I know this is because of some code changes that I did a day back. Ideally any code change should not impact the functionality of the IDE or the driving application.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe `XML` file is invalid since you are getting **invalid character error**.

Comment: What *is* written in the XML file in question, at the position it says (line 2, position 2)?

Answer (score 0):

We use to get those pretty consistently and it started all of sudden, so we ended up reinstalling UFT.

It was very annoying as we have to stop the development and spend time in breaking the locks in QC and restarting QTP.

So if nothing helps,try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your microsoft script debugger version. Upgrade it and see if the issue goes away

download link here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22185

Please accept if this helps.